# Running javascript tests on multiple browsers

Tags: node.js, protractor, karma-jasmine, webdriver-io

Whether it is just nodejs using karma, mocha or webdriver.io, or protractor how would I run cross browser tests on either of these when script is called at once? Which is easier? Any documentation?

Comment: This isn't really a code related question. Probably best to ask it on SE with either [unit-testing](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unit-testing) or [selenium](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/selenium) tags

Answer (score 0):

You can use Multiremote with WebdriverIO.

It allows you to run multiple Selenium sessions in a single test. To do so just use the 'multiremote function' and pass an object with named browser with their capabilities into it. By giving each capability a name you will be able to easy select and access that single instance when executing commands on a single instance. Here is an example demonstrating a how to create a multiremote WebdriverIO instance in standalone mode:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
var browser = webdriverio.multiremote({
myChromeBrowser: {
desiredCapabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome'
}
},
myFirefoxBrowser: {
desiredCapabilities: {
browserName: 'firefox'
}
}
});
```